# Search in Apache Lucene(4.2.0) docs in between somewhere

Tags: apache, lucene

I have multiple documents in lucene having data in such format

> entity : Dalveer Singh
>   subtype : student
>   .... so on

I want to search in an entity(say entity) with value.If I search with: `dalveer*` (starting of value) it returns some result(s), but not when I search something form middle like `*singh` or `*veer*`.

Is there any way of searching the whole line for matching result?

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a QueryParser configuration you have to adjust.
Usually you have the option to allow leading wildcards for your QueryParser. As an example [StandardQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html) with method:

```
setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)
```

It also depends what kind of fields do you use for indexing because this affects the process of analyzing.

- TextField is used for fulltext searches -> text won't be tokenized
- StringField -> text will be tokenized

See [Field JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) for more information about this.